# Null value in XTemplate

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

After a 4.1.1 upgrade I noticed a quirky change in a way how `XTemplate` interprets null value.
Here is an example of what XTemplate does http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/AyJ9v/3/ (note Field 2 value) .
And here is the same but interpreted by Template class: http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/AyJ9v .

When data passed to an XTemplate contains null values string "null" is printed to the output.

If this is a bug in 4.1.1 what is the workaround if I need the use of XTemplate?

Thanks.

**update**: Bug was fixed in 4.1.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This workaround will work (here's the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Izhaki/AyJ9v/4/)):

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate("<p>Field1: {f1}, Field2: {[this.outputField( values.f2 )]} </p>",{
    outputField: function( aValue )
    {
        return aValue == null ? '' : aValue;                
    }
}).compile();
```

Comment: Thanks for posting ... quite ugly, but will work I guess. Turns out it's a bug in 4.1.1 and should be fixed in 4.1.2

Comment: This is the first question I saw where both OP and answerer of Selected Answer have exactly the same reputation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have condition inline.

```
var tpl = new Ext.XTemplate("<tpl if='f2 != null'>{f2}</tpl>" ,
<tpl if='f2 == null'></tpl>").compile();
```